# Shell Scripting including code from an other file

Tags: shell, scripting

I got a question, i'm new to scripting with the unix Shell.
My question , is it possible to include code from an other file without hardcoding?
I want to include the code from file 2 into the file 1.
For example:

File 1:

```
# get groups of user
# remove user from groups 
# remove user
```

File 2:

```
  # add group membership.
    for agroup in ${add_groups[*]:-}; do
      ldapexists posixGroup cn=$agroup || rc=$?
      if [[ "${rc:-0}" = "2" ]]; then
        warn "Skipping non-existant group: $agroup"
      else
        echo -e "\ndn:cn=${agroup},ou=Groups,${basedn}\nchangetype: modify" >> ${TMPFILE}
        echo -e "add: memberUid\nmemberUid: $opuser\n\n" >> ${TMPFILE}
      fi
    done
```

Comment: You want the `source` or `.` command. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins

Comment: @glennjackman  
i do not really know, which is the cleaner or better way?

Comment: Somewhere in file1, add `. /path/to/file2` -- there is a space between the dot and the filename.

Comment: okey thanks, but in the file 2 is more code than just this little cut. How can i  only use only this snipped of code @glennjackman

Comment: You can't. You could extract that bit out into its own file, and then use `.` to include it in other files that need it.

Comment: @glennjackman alright, thank you!